# How to prove that $(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How does one show that $(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ is irrational?

I have got no idea how to solve that, please help!

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: No reason to shout

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If 
$$
(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}=\frac{a}{b},
$$
then
$$
\sqrt{2}=\frac{a^3}{b^3}-2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Assume $(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ is rational. Then $\exists m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{m}{n}$$ where $\dfrac mn$ is a fraction in reduced form.So $$2+\sqrt{2}=\frac{m^3}{n^3}\implies \sqrt{2}=\frac{m^3}{n^3}-2$$ This contradicts the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: We need not write the fractional form, as we have not made explicit use of it!

Answer (score 2):

$$(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}\in\mathbb{Q}\Longrightarrow 2+\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}\Longrightarrow \sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q},$$
contradiction.